# Как мне продолжить создавать фильтр для продуктов?

Tags: jquery

Как мне продолжить создавать фильтр для продуктов?
Есть созданы объекты

```js
var goods = {
 "28292" : {
  "name" : "Банан",
  "cost" : 30,
  "img" : "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jetflat-fruits/90/002_014_banana_banan_plant_herb_fruit_food-128.png",
  "sklad" : "да"
 },
 "23729" : {
  "name" : "Помидор",
  "cost" : 40,
  "img" : "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nature-life-in-color/128/tomato-color-128.png",
  "sklad" : "нет"
 },
 "11223" : {
  "name" : "Клубника",
  "cost" : 60,
  "img" : "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits-and-vegetables-13/32/strawberry-fruit-berry-128.png",
  "sklad" : "да"
 }
};

var filter_goods = {
 price : '',
 nalichye : '',
 name_producnt : {
  'baban' : '',
  'pomidor' : '',
  'clubnika' : ''
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="1.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="out"></div> 
 <div id="filter_goods"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

хочу и кинуть в html и сделать фильтр.
Заранее Спасибо)

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Всмсысле в чём в html

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать и какие трудности при этом возникли?

Comment: хочу сделать фильтр товаров создал только обьекты на js

Comment: И как этот фильтр должен выглядеть?